# How to change values of _get_aggregated_product_quantities in Odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo, odoo-14

I am trying to change the data of `_get_aggregated_product_quantities()` in **Odoo 14**, I don't know why it returns wrong data, I see that in the code it gets the values from `move_line` or `move_id` but when I check them both have correct data.
Does anyone know how I can change the values of the method?